# Multivariate Linear Regression, coefficients don't match

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm facing a problem with different linear models from scikit-learn.
There is my code

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = reg.predict(X_train).reshape(-1)
print(f"R2 on train set:{reg.score(X_train, y_train)}")
print(f"R2 on test set:{reg.score(X_test, y_test)}")
print(f"MSE on train set:{mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred)}")
print(f"MSE on test set:{mean_squared_error(y_test, reg.predict(X_test))}")

output:
>R2 on train set:0.5810258473777401
>R2 on test set:0.5908396388537969
>MSE on train set:0.023576848498732563
>MSE on test set:0.02378699441936436
```

Model is fitted, now I want to get the slope coefficient and the intercept from my model:

```
A, B = reg.coef_[0], reg.intercept_[0]
A, B

output:
>(array([ 0.14373081, -1.8211677 ,  1.81493948,  1.39041689, -0.14027746]),
> 0.060286931992710735)
```

Since I used 5 features to fit the model I also have 5 slope coefficients, ok.

But when I try to [visualize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSd4w.png) y_true, y_pred and the regression (ax +b) it's looks wrong for the regression of the second feature (total rooms). Since it has -1.81 as coef slope it's look logic but if the predictions of the model look fine, how it's possible to have this regression looks that bad, it make no sense right ?

I think that the return of `reg.coef_` is not in the same order as the features the model is fitted with. But as far as I have see, it should be the same order, so idk.

There is also this part of code, that plot the regression *just in case*

```
sns.lineplot(x=X[:, i], y=(a[i]*X[:, i])+b, label="regression", color=c3, alpha=1, ci=None, ax=axes[i])
```

Any idea ?
I keep in mind that there may be no problem at all but visually it hurts a bit

Comment: My best guess is that’s because your x variables are highly correlated, specifically, total rooms and total bedrooms.  My eyeballing suggests that total bedroom’s slope looks too high, and they are roughly the same in magnitude

Comment: @Shffl I already watched the correlation but I still don't understand the gap between the predictions and the regression for total rooms. In fact total rooms & total bedrooms are highly correlated as you mentionned. https://imgur.com/a/orsbds8

Comment: According to your regression, adding an additional bedroom has basically 0 effect on house value (the coefficients are equal in magnitude).  If most of the variation in the data is in the number of bedrooms, plotting y against a single regressor without controlling for the others will look weird for exactly this reason

Comment: You can potentially try to use a confusion matrix.

Comment: @Shffl I understand better, but still, how do you explains the gap between predictions and regression for totals bedrooms. Regression should match better with predictions don't you think ?

Comment: @QiyuZhong I'm not sure about the interest of a confusion matrix in this context (linear regression, continuous values)

Comment: @mattOrNothing - it's not guaranteed.  As an example, think about y = x1 - x2 + noise.  If you plot the marginals of y, you'll see something similar to what you have.  Namely: a) the predictions look right, but the fitted line looks awful

Comment: @Shffl Alright, looks logic, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

y_pred is a quantifier for listreg. We introduce N as an other variable which cannot be quantified or consecutive.
N=ax/k-b of a scatter plot. This helps to find the total shape or size of the bedroom; b, b=l.
5 is right. 5 is independent of the regression. I mean of an independent variable.